# Como criar uma classe a partir de outra classe? (Hierarquia)

Tags: javascript

Olá, pessoal.

Possuo as classe Estudantes, EstudanteMonitor e EstudanteEstagiario.
Essas duas últimas classes herdam todos os métodos e atributos da classe Estudante (nome, matricula, sexo, notas, exibir(), atribuirNota(), lerNota(), calcularMedia()) e adicionam uns novos para elas.

Há como criar essas duas últimas classes de forma que a classe Estudante seja pai delas?

```
    var Estudante = function (nome, matricula, sexo) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.matricula = matricula;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    var notas = [];

    this.exibir = function () {
        return "oi";
    };

    this.atribuirNota = function (n) {
        nota.push(n);
    };

    this.lerNota = function (index) {
        return [index-1];
    };

    calcularMedia = function () {
        var x = (notas.length);
        var soma = 0;
        for (i=0;  i<(x - 1); i++ ){
            soma += notas[i];
        }
        var media = soma / x;
        return media;

    }
}

var EstudanteMonitor = Object.create(Estudante);
EstudanteMonitor.prototype.constructor = EstudanteMonitor;

var e1 = new EstudanteMonitor("oi", 2, 3);
console.log(e1.nome);
```

Um exemplo de como estou tentando fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, você deve declarar assim:

```
function EstudanteMonitor() {

}
// Aqui vai a herança, você diz que o prototype de EstudanteMonitor é Estudante
EstudanteMonitor.prototype = new Estudante();
var e= new EstudanteMonitor();
console.log(e.exibir())
```

Para herdar também o construtor, deve fazer assim:

```
function EstudanteMonitor(nome, matricula, sexo) {
   Estudante.call( this, nome, matricula, sexo );
}
```

Note que EstudanteMonitor não tem uma definição para `exibir()`, mas vai funcionar por causa da herança;

Veja mais aqui: http://loopinfinito.com.br/2012/05/04/heranca-em-javascript-parte-1/

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas ele não pode herdar os atributos também? Exemplo:
function EstudanteMonitor(nome, matricula, sexo) {

}
// Aqui vai a herança, você diz que o prototype de EstudanteMonitor é Estudante
EstudanteMonitor.prototype = new Estudante();
EstudanteMonitor.prototype.constructor = EstudanteMonitor;

var e = new EstudanteMonitor(1, 2, 3);
console.log(e.nome); //retornaria '1', mas retorna undefined.

Comment: Mas ele herda os atributos, o que não herda é o construtor, você tem que definir o mesmo construtor na `function EstudanteMonitor`. Para confirmar, crie na classe Estudante um atributo que não é atribuído pelo construtor, `this.idade = 18;` por exemplo, e tente no final usar um `console.log(e.idade);` para ver o resultado.

Comment: Se eu entendi, colocando os parâmetros na função não deveria funcionar?
 `var Estudante = function (nome, matricula, sexo) {
         //... 
}

function EstudanteMonitor(nome, matricula, sexo) {
 this.nome;
 this.matricula = matricula;
 this.sexo = sexo;

}
// Aqui vai a herança, você diz que o prototype de EstudanteMonitor é Estudante
EstudanteMonitor.prototype = new Estudante();
EstudanteMonitor.prototype.constructor = EstudanteMonitor;

var e = new EstudanteMonitor("carlos", 2, 3);
console.log(e.nome);`//Continua retornando undefined.

Comment: Quase isso, mas você tem que chamar a classe pai usando isso no construtor: `Estudante.call( this, nome, matricula, sexo );`
Veja a minha resposta, editei com o exemplo

Comment: Consegui! Muito obrigado, moço(e desculpe por tantas perguntas)!

Comment: precisando só perguntar

Answer (score 2):

A maneira moderna de fazer isso é com classes implementadas na versão ES6/ES2015 do JavaScript/ECMAScript. Isso já está disponivel em quase todos os browsers. Nesse caso a sintave é:

```
class EstudanteMonitor extends Estudante {
```

e ficaria assim:

```
class Estudante {
    constructor(nome, matricula, sexo) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.notas = [];
    }

    exibir() {
        return 'Nome do estudante: ' + this.nome;
    }

    atribuirNota(n) {
        this.notas.push(n);
    }

    lerNota(index) {
        return this.notas[index - 1];
    }

    calcularMedia() {
        var x = (this.notas.length);
        var soma = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < (x - 1); i++) {
            soma += this.notas[i];
        }
        var media = soma / x;
        return media;
    }
}

class EstudanteMonitor extends Estudante {
    exibir() {
        return 'Nome do estudante monitor: ' + this.nome;
    }
};

var e1 = new Estudante("João", 2, 3);
console.log(e1.exibir()); // "Nome do estudante: João
var em1 = new EstudanteMonitor("João", 2, 3);
console.log(em1.exibir()); // "Nome do estudante monitor: João"
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/py0r32xk/